# NativeDroid HTML5 JS css jQueryMobile template is crashing in iOS7

Tags: javascript, css, html, ios7, nativedroid

I started developing a mobile solution on NativeDroid template which is an HTML5 JS css template (http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/) .. Recently a friend of mine told me that the template is not working on iOS7 running devices. I tried it in several devices.

When you run also from the demo on this site for example the forms sample pages it is stopping.

Is there any feature in iOS7 which is not supported anymore and may cause stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it crashes on iOS devices are in the following lines of CSS in `jquerymobile.nativedroid.css`:

```
.ui-checkbox input,.ui-radio input {
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

if you remove the `width: 1px; height: 1px;`-Attributes it works properly.

```
.ui-checkbox input,.ui-radio input {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

It's pretty strange if you can crash a browser with two simple lines of code - but no browser is perfect ;-)

I've fixed this issue in the current Version 0.2.6 for jQM 1.4.x

You can download the hotfixed css files here:

v0.2.4 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.2.4/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

v0.2.3 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.2.3/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

v0.2.2 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.2.2/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

v0.2.1 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.2.1/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

v0.2.0 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.2/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

v0.1.0 - http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/v0.1/css/jquerymobile.nativedroid.css

Answer (score 1):

I experience something similar. It works perfectly fine in Android 4.4.2. and in most desktop browsers ( linux, windows and Mac ). Specifically checking a checkbox in a form from this theme is crashing my iPads browsers ( both Safari and Chrome ). I'm using iOS 7.1.1.The checkboxes at the demos from jquerymobile.com are working fine in all the devices, so the problem is some kind of incompatibility between the theme and the browsers in iOS7. Probably something can be fixed at the .js file. Still hadn't found a concrete solution of the problem but at least the problematic component is detected. I tested the form without checkboxes and it works fine with the other components.

Comment: Thank you. İt is nice at least to know just checkbox is crashing. Anyway, i changed my decision to use kendo-ui for mobile which is opensource now.  Thanks again